# Redefine GCC floating point storage format

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

I am currently working on an ARM floating point project which needs to change the GCC floating point output format. The default GCC float point represented inside memory is IEEE754 format, which is very inefficient for my MCU structure. I hope to change the float point format inside memory as following: 32 bit 2's complement exponent and 32 bit 2's complement mantissa. Is there any simple way to get GCC to support it?

Comment: Sure: implement the whole corresponding code. Alternatively, use custom types (e.g. a struct).

Comment: 32 bit exponent is too large, far larger than the total number of particles in the universe

Comment: The performance problem may not be primarily an issue with the use of IEEE-754 formats, but rather inefficient libraries. When I last worked with ARM about 10 years ago, FPU-less ARM processor were common, but the FP emulation code incorporated into tool chains was very slow. I wrote my own IEEE-754 single precision primitives (in assembly language) and managed to boost performance by a factor of five, IIRC. [This paper](http://www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/arith16/papers/ARITH16_Iordache.pdf) can give you a good idea about the performance of good implementations.

Comment: The format is not your problem. Unpacking and packing IEEE float is a tiny cost compared to actually performing the arithmetic operations. If soft-float is too costly, don't use float.

Comment: Does your storage format meet the requirements of the C standard (§5.2.4.2.2 "Characteristics of floating types `<float.h>`")?  If so, then the chances are that you can, with enough effort, persuade GCC to support it.  OTOH, I'd be surprised if you can justify the level of effort required.

Comment: Catching up with the status of emulated floating-point it seems that in 2004, Nicolas Pitre delivered an extremely high performance FP emulation for gcc. See [this post](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2004-10/msg01018.html). The performance data posted looks impressive, a bit faster than what I managed to achieve (I only recall approximate cycle counts for mine). If your tool chain is already incorporating Pitre's code, and floating-point is still too slow, you may need to look for alternatives, like S15.16 fixed-point. This will be faster but may have issues with dynamic range, for example

Comment: Thanks for comments ! The format does effect the performance, since all lib functions implementation based on it. Compare the same multiply function for the proposal format and the IEEE 754, will see the difference.

Comment: http://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/22436-1.php

Comment: @Olaf Could you give me a little bit more detail instruction? I just know little about GCC.

Comment: @davidli It is certainly true that the use of a custom format may save a few cycles compared to use of the IEEE-754 format. However, that requires that the custom code for the custom format is written by a person with the equivalent amount of expertise; such talent is rarely available. I do have that expertise; even so when I considered a custom format on ARM in 2001 I discarded the idea because the performance increase was too small compared to the hassle of having to create new infrastructure around that custom format, e.g. when simply wanting to output the data with `printf()` for debugging